# How to measure voltage above Reference Volt using MSP430?

Tags: msp430, adc

I am learning to use MSP430 FR5994 for microcontroller development.

I wish to measure an external voltage using the built in ADC, **the external voltage is in the range of 2.2V to 3.3V**. The reference voltage set for the board is 1.2V (I can't use AVCC as the reference).

**May I ask how should I measure the value of this voltage?**

Comment: Maybe you should ask on Electronics but let me spoil you the answer. A simple voltage divider will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found an introduction to it on Wikipedia.